# Get the result from Rubocop

Tags: ruby, git, rubocop, autocorrect

With this command we can run Rubocop autofix for modified files after committing:

```
git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only head origin/master | xargs rubocop -a
```

Note that I'm comparing my current branch with master. So after this, we can get some newly modified files from Rubocop autofix, and at this point, our repo basically contains 3 types of files:

1. Files that are completely fixed and don't violate Rubocop anymore.
2. Files that are partly fixed but still violate some rules.
3. Files that are too messy Rubocop can't help anything but to leave it alone.

I need to know all the file name of each 3 types above, but how can I do that?

Comment: I don't know if there's a better way, but a simple script could just check: If the return code is 0, it's completely fixed (or never needed fixing); else if the last line contains "corrected" then it's partially fixed; else the file was unfixable.

Comment: And if you want to split that first result up further into files that were corrected vs never needed correcting, you could check whether the last line contains "no offenses".